# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'rate' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project and in this project which is a *Movie Storage*, I have a One to One Relationship between `movies` table and `imdbs` table.

So I have already added the relationships into Models like this:

`Movie.php`:

```
public function imdb()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Imdb::class);
    }
```

And `Imdb.php`:

```
protected $fillable = ['rate','movie_id'];
public function movie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Movie::class);
    }
```

And the Migration of `imdbs` table goes here:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('imdbs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('rate');
            $table->integer('movie_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

As you can see I have set `movie_id` which defines the `id` column of `movies` table.

Now in order to retrieve data on Blade, I did this:

```
@foreach($movies  as $movie)
<tr>
   <th scope="row">{{ $movie->id }}</th>
   <td>{{ $movie->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $movie->year }}</td>
   <td>{{ $movie->imdb->rate }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And the `$movies` variable comes from this Method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $movies = Movie::with('imdb')->get();
        return view('admin.movies.index')->with('movies', $movies);
    }
```

But the problem is, I get this error message:

> **ErrorException** Trying to get property 'rate' of non-object

However the `rate` already has some data in it:

[image]

I don't know how to fix this, because everything looks fine and correct.

Comment: some of your movies may have not imdb object?
you need to check in this case if movie has imdb  or not

Comment: as example `optional($movie->imdb)->rate ?? 'not rated yet'`

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem is not about `rate` having or not having data. The problem is that `$movie->imdb` is not an object (which will happen when a Movie doesn't have an associated Imdb record).

Comment: @El_Vanja How to fix this

Comment: You can fix it by adding a check to see if the movie has an object associated.  See my answer :)

Comment: A fix has already been proposed in both the answer and the second comment.

Comment: change the with by $movies = Movie::with('imdbs')->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your movie may not have an imdb object with the movie's id associated.

To fix, provide a check on the view to determine if it exists:

For example, change:

```
<td>{{ $movie->imdb->rate }}</td>
```

to

```
@if($movie->imdb !== null)
    <td>{{ $movie->imdb->rate }}</td>
@else 
    <td> N/A </td>
@endif
```